# SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT) doesn't work

Tags: c, winapi, text, gdi

When I use `SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);` in the code below, I got the following effect when I resize the main window (and hence when the child receives the WM_PAINT message):

[image]

The problem is : When I resize the main window, The old area of "Find:" shoule be erased, I guess. But it just remains there.

If I don't use `SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);`, I don't have this problem. It looks like:

[image]

, i.e it has white background. Furthermore, if I use `SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);`, it looks like the same as above, before I resize the main window. So I don't think `SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);` works here.

the `hwnd` is a static child with style `SS_BITMAP`.

Do you know why this issue occurs?

```
switch (message) {
    case WM_PAINT:
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        SelectObject(hdc, gDefaultGuiFont);
        SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);

        RECT rc;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
        DrawText(hdc, _TR("Find:"), -1, &rc, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        return 0;

     .............
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? You draw "Find" and get hieroglyphs?

Comment: No. I upload a new image to make the problem clear.

Comment: Looks like this is toolbar portion. Thought, it does not need to be resizable?

Comment: @Maximus, I don't understand what you mean. When I resize the main window, it call a function to resize the toolbar. I put a static child control with SS_BITMAP style and I want to display `Find:` on this static control.

Comment: Seems to me, you change the **height** of toolbar?

Comment: If I resize the main window from the right or bottom border, no such issue. But if I resize the main window from the left or upper border, the issue occurs.

Comment: In any case, the height of the toolbar is not changed. But its width may change.

Comment: What window is `hwnd` in your code? toolbar/main window?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "fixed" rectangles. For example

```
    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
    rc.left += ...; rc.top += ...; // shift up-left point
    DrawText(hdc, _TR("Find:"), -1, &rc, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_LEFT | DT_TOP);
```

The idea is you draw text in wrong position (once) and in right position (twice) while backgound updated only once. Can't say more on part of code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that windows is not updating the control (in time) that's behind your static control, you are now responsible for it's contents. So you want to use the background provided by the parent. Well just ask the parent to draw it for you in the child window:

```
RECT rc;
GetClientRectRelative(m_hWnd, GetParent(m_hWnd), &rc);
SetWindowOrgEx(m_mdc, rc.left, rc.top, NULL);
SendMessage(GetParent(m_hWnd), WM_PAINT, (WPARAM)(HDC)m_mdc);
SetWindowOrgEx(m_mdc, 0, 0, NULL);
```

In which

```
bool GetClientRectRelative(HWND hWnd, HWND hWndRelativeTo, RECT *pRect)
{
    RECT rcWnd, rcRelativeTo;
    if (!GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcWnd) ||
            !ClientToScreen(hWnd, (POINT*)&rcWnd) ||
            !ClientToScreen(hWnd, (POINT*)&rcWnd + 1) ||
            !GetClientRect(hWndRelativeTo, &rcRelativeTo) || 
            !ClientToScreen(hWndRelativeTo, (POINT*)&rcRelativeTo) ||
            !ClientToScreen(hWndRelativeTo, (POINT*)&rcRelativeTo + 1))
        return false;

    pRect->top = rcWnd.top - rcRelativeTo.top;
    pRect->left = rcWnd.left - rcRelativeTo.left;
    pRect->right = rcWnd.right - rcRelativeTo.left;
    pRect->bottom = rcWnd.bottom - rcRelativeTo.top;

    return true;
}
```

Now draw anything you like, I suggest you'd use the `TRANSPARENT` background mode.

Please create all your child windows with the styles `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` and `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS`, then these problems will become apparent immediately and you avoid flicker.